# pkg-config flags are relative

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile [bmdtools](https://github.com/lu-zero/bmdtools) with a custom built version of [libav 11](https://libav.org/download/) which I compiled under `~/libav-11.8/build` using g++ 4.8.4 under Ubuntu 14.04.
bmd uses pkg-config to build g++ flags, and since compilation fails on the linking phase, I tested pkg-config output as follows:

```
echo `pkg-config --cflags --libs libavcodec libavformat libswscale libavutil`
```

which yelds

```
-I/usr/local/include -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec
-ldl -lasound -lz -lwscale -lavutil -lm
```

So I figured `-I` and `-L` flags where not set to the custom build location. Setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/libav-11.8/build/lib/pkgconfig` and running it again yelded

```
-Ibuild/include -pthread -Lbuild/lib ...<lib flags>
```

which would be correct if I ran g++ from the build root folder. Shouldn't pkg-config resolve to an absolute path instead of a relative one? What is the rationale behind this behaviour?

Comment: Presumably it's reading `pkg-config` files under `~/libav-11.8/build/lib/pkgconfig`; look for files with a `.pc` extension — what do they contain? I'm guessing you'll find the relative paths in there...

Comment: I did find those, but they use `prefix` variable, which is set to `build`, in the `Libs` and `Cflags` section. That way it cannot be used to compile dependent libs which are not in the same root folder.

Answer (score 2):

After reading [Freedesktop Guide to pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html) I realized pkg-config does nothing to validate whether binaries, libraries or paths are accurate. It only spits out what is written in the `Libs` and `Cflags` of the `.pc` files.

In my case those are created by libav's compilation process and use the `prefix` variable passed to `configure`.

So after recompiling libav with `prefix` set to an absolute path, pkg-config will output `-I` and `-L` flags appropriate for use in the compilation of other projects.